# A string between two accelerating spaceships vs two falling spaceships

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, string, rocket-science

According to [Bell's spaceship paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_spaceship_paradox), a string between two uniformly accelerating spaceships will break. According to the equivalence principle, a string between two spaceships freely falling in a uniform gravitational field won't break.

The difference has already been explained with math. Can you also explain the mere fact of the string breaking or not in a concise, verbal way without resorting to very specialized terms, unless necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume an uniform gravity field. (Which only means that tidal forces are absent, do not assume some uniformity that a "uniform gravity field" does not have)

Gravitational time dilation causes the lower spaceship to fall at slower speed than the upper spaceship. That causes a length contraction of the distance between the spaceships. The distance gets contracted the same amount that a rope connecting the spaceships gets contracted.

Comment: Do you also mean that the falling spaceships, even if communicating, wouldn't be able to detect that time dilation?

Comment: @scriptfoo Yes. Can't detect time dilation, can't detect length contraction.

Comment: By assuming no tidal forces, you have assumed flat spacetime and therefore the Rindler metric. In this case the acceleration due to gravity goes as $1/x$ so it is questionable whether one should call this a uniform field. But apart from that it is a good answer. However it is not true, in the comments, that two spaceships falling in this way will not detect a gravitational time dilation, If A sends repeated pulses to B, for example, then the time elapsed at B between the pulses is different from that at A. That is gravitational time dilation,

Comment: @AndrewSteane   Rindler-fish feels its weight decreasing when it is winched up, Rindler-fisher feels the weight of said fish staying constant. Equivalence principle: In flat spacetime free-fallers should not feel any effects of gravity.

Comment: @stuffu Oh yes, that it is a lovely observation. But my point about timing of repeated pulses remains. (It would be interpreted as a Doppler effect if one analysed the whole thing in a single global inertial frame).

Comment: @AndrewSteane  Well, I trust equivalence principle. Do you take into account that lower faller's speed is closer to the local maximum speed than what the upper faller's speed is? (fishing line snaps - initial coordinate acceleration of fish is the same everywhere, but coordinate speed of light is not the same everywhere)  (the lower faller propably recieves redshifted light pulses)

Comment: @stuffu Yes that is taken into account. Consider a vertical rocket described by Rindler metric, The clocks at the top are ticking faster than the clocks at the bottom. But perhaps you were saying something else, namely that there would be no time dilation for inertially moving spaceships here, which is of course correct.

Comment: @AndrewSteane I know that observer standing on the floor of an accelerating rocket says that a clock at higher potential ticks faster. And if said observer jumps up, during his freefall he says that the aforementioned effect disappears. No gravitational time dilation effects in freefall.   I didn't bother with making the clocks to make a jump too ... that doesn't matter. Anyway, I am right. Freefallers do not detect any effects of gravity   ;)

Comment: @stuffu We are both making true statements, just different ones.

Answer (score 1):

The accelerating spaceships in the case where the string breaks have been programmed so as to have the same acceleration relative to the starting frame at any given time in that starting frame. The freely falling spaceships have different accelerations relative to their starting frame at any given time in that starting frame, so the two situations are not equivalent.

If the accelerating spaceships were instead programmed so as to maintain a constant proper distance between them (in their own instantaneous rest frame) then the string would not break. In this case the proper acceleration of the leading rocket is smaller than the proper acceleration of the trailing rocket. This case would be the right one to compare with the freely falling rockets in a certain type of gravitational field.

In the gravitational field of a spherical body such as a neutron star, a long string extended in the vertical direction between freely falling masses will be in tension and will eventually break when this tension exceeds the tensile strength of the string.

Comment: So, if I release two masses at the same time in the frame when they start at rest, then: Will the distance between them  increase or not  in a constant gravitational field?

Comment: Why "the freely falling spaceships have different accelerations relative to their starting frame"?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Using Newtonian gravity (which is sufficient for weak field limit of GR) the distance between the masses is constant when measured in the starting frame, and therefore the proper distance between them is getting larger.

Comment: @scriptfoo If the scenario is one in which the string is not drawn into tension, then the gravitational environment must be one in which the local acceleration due to gravity is not the same everywhere.

Comment: @Andrew do you mean that in a uniform gravitational field the string would break?

Comment: right, so then the acceleration is the same at all times in the frame the start at rest, like in Bell's paradox, so why do you say that the situation is different?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny The puzzle here may be to do with definitions. A uniform gravitational field is not the same thing as one which leads to constant proper acceleration. Also acceleration relative to starting frame is not the same as proper acceleration. To get everything pinned down in the end one has to write the math, but that is what the question asked us not to do. The bottom line is that one can invent a "gravitational field" which does not give rise to tidal effects (so string does not break) but such a field is not uniform, it corresponds to the Rindler metric.

Comment: I see, thanks....